# Apache as Reverse Proxy on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-server, apache

I need to run Apache HTTP Server on Windows.

According to [Apache Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html#down) there are 5 popular distributions:

- ApacheHaus
- Apache Lounge
- BitNami WAMP Stack
- WampServer
- XAMPP

So far i used XAMPP but according to [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/q/911242/391060) it should not be used for production environments.

Requirements:

- Running on Windows and recommended for production environments
- These modules must run: mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http, mod_proxy_ajp, mod_ssl, mod_proxy_wstunnel
- Apache must run as windows service

Which distribution of Apache for Windows would fit in that requirements and work the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamp, Wampserver and Bitnami Wamp Stack are for development. They are a "easy install" soft that install all you need for do some web development. The other two are what you are looking for; any will work fine. There are some manual installation for the modules needed though.

But please note that configuring a reverse proxy is not a install only procedure, some config is needed. Most of what you will need to do is on the apache foundation itself (see [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html))
.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Reverse proxy configuration is already running on Linux and also on Xampp, so if mod_proxy (http, ajp, wstunnel) are working, then I'm happy :)